# facebook realtime update upon user checkin

Tags: facebook, scala, facebook-graph-api, checkin

My app needs to know whenever users check into a specific merchant's location.

FB Realtime update sends a POST request notifying user's location is changed, then my application will have to make a GET request to FB in finding out if user has checked in to THAT merchant's location for which application is watching updates for.

What's the best way to design/implement this? Should my app store longitude/latitude of each merchant whose location we are interested in tracking? And then GET request which will bring back user's current location with longitude/latitude. should I be comparing those two values?Not sure if this will be an accurate(and idiomatic) way to confirm if user checked into a very specific merchant's venue?

Comment: Anyone any idea or guidance on this?